# Copying elements from HTML using Bs4 to list as seperate indexes

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, spyder

I want extract odds from a website. Underneath you can see my code. I've used .find_all() to find the div tags with the class = odd_value where the odds are located between span tags. When I append it to the list it copies all of the elements to the list as one index.[Here is my code where I have printed the length of the list, to show you my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHXLI.png)

How do I copy each div tag with the class = odd_value as seperate indexes instead of just one big index, to my list: listOdds

Comment: Could you put your code instead of picture?

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: edit > copy/paste your code > select your code > click on brackets {} > done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find_all()` returns a ResultSet (subclass of a list) of matched filters, and you are appending that to another list using `.append()` therefor your list becomes `[[<div ..., <div ..., ...]]` and the length of that is 1.

So to fix that you can simply assign it to `listOdds` variable like this:

```
listOdds = sovs.find_all("div", {"class": "odd_value"})
```

Or to make it joinable you can convert each item to string by doing:

```
listOdds = list(map(str, sovs.find_all("div", {"class": "odd_value"})))
```